# Get a word's definition using PHP?

Tags: php, definition, words

I have something where it randomly generates words using PHP...
I have a iFrame currently linking to dictionary.com...
I don't like this because it's old and ugly.
I want to get the definition of a word and display it how I want!
Is this possible by using PHP?

Comment: If you have a database with terms and definitions, or access to one (by some method).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use PHP to check the definition of a word, and you're using a Unix-based platform, check out this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415615/is-there-any-api-to-integrate-with-english-dictionary-in-php

Answer (score 4):

If you like dictionary.com, maybe consider using its API? See http://developer.dictionary.com